# Change link color in MediaWiki navigation panel

Tags: html, tags, hyperlink, mediawiki

I want to change the visited link colors of navigation panel.

I succeed changing the link colors for my main body:
'.\mediawiki\skins\common\commonElements.css' -> .mw-body a.extiw:visited OK

But I can't find the proper file and the proper ID for it. Could you help me out?

Appreciate that.

Comment: Do not change MediaWiki files. The correct to change CSS is to use the administrative interface: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Interface/Stylesheets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main CSS file resides within the `/skins/vector/` folder. Can you check in there? 
In my experience, it is the `a:visited` property you'll need to modify, but by using any HTML inspector (F12 in IE and Ctrl+Shift+C in Chrome) you'll be able to find it quickly.

Comment: You are right, /skins/vector/screen.css -> div#mw-panel div.portal div.body ul li a:visited